# how to display rating based on number

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, node.js

I have a situation where i'm getting `data`  from `database` like this

```
var data = [  {name:'Alpha Hotel',price:400,star:3},
              {name:'Beta Hotel',price:600,star:4},
              {name:'Gamma Hotel',price:450,star:5},
           ];
```

i want to display as much `rating` as my `star`

for example for this `data`   `{name:'Alpha Hotel',price:400,star:3}`  my `rating` should be `3` not `1`

**here is what i have tried:**  https://jsfiddle.net/ewL4wLvh/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `loop` for form `star` markup to be appended-

[**`Array#fill`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) - ***The `fill()` method fills all the elements of an array from a start index to an end index with a static value.***

[**`Array#reduce`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) - ***The `reduce()` method applies a function against an accumulator and each element in the array (from left to right) to reduce it to a single value.***

```js
var data = [{
  name: 'Alpha Hotel',
  price: 400,
  star: 3
}, {
  name: 'Beta Hotel',
  price: 600,
  star: 4
}, {
  name: 'Gamma Hotel',
  price: 450,
  star: 5
}, ];

var htmlConstructed = '';
$.each(data, function(i, val) {
  var starStr = Array(val.star).fill(null).reduce((a) => a + '<i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true" style="color:#D91E18;"></i>', '');
  htmlConstructed += '<p>Name : ' + val.name + '</p>' + '<p>Price : ' + val.price + '</p>' + 'Rating :<span>' + starStr + '</span><hr/>';
});
$('#content-area').append(htmlConstructed);
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content-area"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

While constructing the HTML, you need to repeat the `spans` as many times as of stars.
You can use this neat trick to achieve this without using loops:

```
htmlConstructed += '<p>Name : '+val.name+'</p>'+
    '<p>Price : '+val.price+'</p>'+
    'Rating :'+new Array(val.star + 1).join('<span><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true" style="color:#D91E18;"></i></span>')+
    '<hr/>';
```

Check out the updated [**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/ewL4wLvh/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditions(if, else if, elf), and check how much stars it has, and then display how much stars it has.

Answer (score 0):

use `Array.join` for times that you want repeat some element.

```
var data = [  {name:'Alpha Hotel',price:400,star:3},
          {name:'Beta Hotel',price:600,star:4},
          {name:'Gamma Hotel',price:450,star:5},
       ];

var htmlConstructed = '';
 $.each(data,function(i,val){        
      htmlConstructed += '<p>Name : '+val.name+'</p>'+'<p>Price : '+val.price+'</p>'+'Rating :<span>'+
      Array(val.star).join('<i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true" style="color:#D91E18;"></i>')
  +'</span><hr/>';

  });

  $('#content-area').append(htmlConstructed);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this simple solution.

```
var data = [  {name:'Alpha Hotel',price:400,star:3},
                  {name:'Beta Hotel',price:600,star:4},
                  {name:'Gamma Hotel',price:450,star:5},
               ];

        var htmlConstructed = '';
         $.each(data,function(i,val){
             // console.log(val.name);
             var rating='';
             for(var i=0;i<val.star;i++){
                    rating = rating +'<span><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true" style="color:#D91E18;"></i></span>';
             }
              htmlConstructed += '<p>Name : '+val.name+'</p>'+'<p>Price : '+val.price+'</p>'+'Rating :'+rating+'<hr/>';


     });

     $('#content-area').append(htmlConstructed);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this Code,

```
var data = [  {name:'Alpha Hotel',price:400,star:3},
              {name:'Beta Hotel',price:600,star:4},
              {name:'Gamma Hotel',price:450,star:5},
           ];

    var htmlConstructed = '';
     $.each(data,function(i,val){
         // console.log(val.name);

          htmlConstructed += '<p>Name : '+val.name+'</p>'+'<p>Price : '+val.price+'</p>'+'Rating :'+ addStar(val.star) +'<hr/>';

 });

 function addStar(rating){
 var returnString = '';
 for(var i=0;i< rating;i++ )
 returnString = returnString + '<span><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true" style="color:#D91E18;"></i></span>';

 return returnString;

 }

 $('#content-area').append(htmlConstructed);
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/r83wnpqr/